# Can the OpenAPI servers list be made dynamic/optional?

Tags: openapi

Our OpenAPI definition is the reference for our customers;
they generate their clients from it.

But this definition is also useful with a `servers:` section inside:

- Hit "Try it out"
- Select a server destination
- Fill in the REST method parameters

and send the request, and you're doing a quick experiment of a feature.

```yaml
openapi: '3.0.2'
info:
  title: Application interfaces
  version: '1.0.0'
    name: Our application
    url: http://x.y.z.com

servers:
  - url: http://localhost:8088
    description: local debug 

  - url: https://test1.xyz.com/
    description: Test env 1

  - url: https://test2.xyz.com/
    description: Test env 2
```

But when it's time for delivery, our customer should not see these servers that have little interest for them, and we have to remove them.

Is there a way to shape the OpenAPI definition so that we could have this list of servers filled, but others would not see them?

Comment: you can use a yaml parser or other to to mechanically add/remove them as needed

Comment: The current workaround is another branch created on Git, where this `servers:` section is set. Then, merges or rebases from the main definition are done to stay at the correct level of definition. This allow to execute REST request directly from this Gitlab page when it is displaying this dedicated branch.